# jQuery - Is it possible to have separate onHover and onClick events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, onhover

I am currently building a website that uses alot of jQuery, it involves having an interactive map.

There will be points on the map, but what I need is, when you hover over the map point, a small description is shown (perhaps in a div called .mapitem-smalldescription) and then when you CLICK on the map point, a much larger full description with pictures would be shown (in another div called, for example  .mapitem-fulldescription)

I know how to do onclick and onhover events on SEPERATE map points, but I have not been able to successfuly combine them together onto a single map points.

How can I do this please?

Zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each one of your map points had the class **point** this might work:

**Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nrwyz/8/ .**

**Code:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="point">
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".point").live("mouseover", function() {
    //code to show description
    $(this).append('<div class="mapitem-smalldescription">Small description</div>');
});

$(".point").live("mouseout", function() {
    //code to show description
    $(".mapitem-smalldescription").fadeOut(200);
});

$(".point").live("click", function() {
    //code to full description
    $(this).append('<div class="mapitem-fulldescription">Full description</div>');

});
```

**CSS**

```
.point {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #550000;
}

.mapitem-smalldescription {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #00FF00;
}

.mapitem-fulldescription {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

---

**EDIT: Here is a version which behaves more closely to the way you described: http://jsfiddle.net/nrwyz/23/ .
Let me know if there is anything else you need modified or added.**

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Kevin - How would I stop ".mapitem-smalldescription" from appearing when hovering over the full description?  It seems as though the "hover" event is extending to ".mapitem-fulldescription" when it is appended.  I tried a few things to stop it from appearing, but I can't make it work.  Thanks

Comment: To expand, the append event seems to be occuring infinitely, if you hover over the map-point at more than one location AND if you then hover over the appended div.   Is there a solution to stop this as it not only causes graphical glitches, it also loads an long amount of data into the browser as its occuring infinitely.   Thanks

Comment: I'll see if I can edit the code a little to make the reult a little more desirable. I apologize for the roughness of the original code, it was just a really quick mockup.

Comment: @Zach Nicodemous I modified my old code to allow the code to behave more closely to the way you described. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nrwyz/23/ .

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that each map point will have the class `mappoint`:

```
$('.mappoint').hover(function() {
    //do something on mouseover...
}, function() {
    //do something on mouseout...
}).click(function() {
    //do something on click...
});
```